# How to concatenate two float values in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an application, and I am not able to concatenate two float values.

Comment: float values can't be concatenated.

Comment: are you trying to format two float values as a string? concatenating two floats directly makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a string with the string representation of two `float`s concatenated, try:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f", float1, float2];
```